# Define AWS credentials in nodejs deployment on EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker

I need guidance regarding using AWS-SDK credentials in production nodejs app.

What is the possible way of doing this? I researched about it that always use shared credentials files for aws credentials using that link. "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html"

So I'm confused about the way. Do I need to create that file in that Linux path specified in that link in VM of EC2?

I made a new IAM role for S3 and allocate it to a specific EC2 instance but through code how can I be able to access S3 services. I deployed my app and it's still giving me access denied error on accessing S3 service.

Do I still need to include credentials file as discussed in like given above? And Do I still need to initialize S3?

```
const s3 = new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId,
  secretKey,
  bucketRegion,
});
```

Please guide me that how can I deploy nodejs app without affecting AWS services.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [AWS Well Architected Framework](https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/well-architected/) the best solution would be to assign a role with your required permissions to the EC2 instance that you are going to use.

You should strive from adding credentials to the application directly as they are not needed in most of the cases.

Please take a look at [IAM roles for Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) as how does AWS guides to achieving that.